# How to make parent container grow when absolutely positioned text area grows/overflows

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a parent container (div) that contains an absolutely positioned text area that grows (vertically and horizontally) to fit its content. Unfortunately, because it's absolutely positioned, when it gets to a certain width or height it'll overflow the container.

What I would like to do is grow the parent div to match the text area as it grows beyond it. But I'm not sure at all how to go about doing this at all and would love any advice. (Note: I can't use JQuery)

Edit: Provided similar example

Sample codepen: https://codepen.io/flubzmcgubz/pen/KKdwYRd

html:

```
 <div class='frame'>

      <span class="absolute" contenteditable="true">sdfsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssd</span>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.frame {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 400px;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80vw;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible because when you absolute position an element, you also break the relationship with its parent, so the parent is no longer impacted by the child size